# Comparing a plural noun with a singular noun: "They [do something] like a bat"

Tags: grammatical-number

The narrator in [this](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/GbCQ99BnrUo) video has a very clear native English accent. What caught my attention is near the end of the clip when he said:

> **They** spend so much time in the tree and they sleep while hanging upside down **like a bat**.

Though I know that it's grammatically correct to compare a plural noun with a singular noun, such as:

> They are much slower than him.

Or:

> They ran as slow as a turtle.

However, I am still wondering how often (or rare) for native speakers to compare many "lemurs" with plural "bats" instead of a single "bat" in the first sentence, or at least isn't it abnormal to do so?

Comment: I would find “bats” more natural. Of course spoken English is less formal than written English.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your input! Just curious to know if you're also a native English speaker as your name hints at it?

Comment: Yes I was born and lived my life in Australia. I have updated my profile to reflect this.

Comment: What could you change "slower than him" to? There's only one "him", so you can't make it plural. All the people being compared are each slower than him.

Comment: It doesn't sound like an English (i.e. British) accent to me, he sounds very American.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the singular *bat* actually tells us something about how we are supposed to interpret the plural subject. As others have pointed out, the description of their behavior applies to each of them. It isn't about the group's behavior being similar to the communal behavior of bats.

Critter plurals can be quite ambiguous out of context. We could be describing each member. We could be describing emergent behavior of a conspecific group that can't be deduced from the behavior of individuals. Or the plural could be referring to multiple species or breeds or whatever.

So the choice of *a bat* vs *a colony of bats* vs just *bats* provides context and limits the ambiguity. I would tend to only use the bare plural of an animal when referring to groups of more than one species. I would explicitly use the normal names of social groups if referring to communal traits, and I would use the singular for comparing traits of individuals.

This ambiguity is commonly a problem with animals, but can also appear when talking about teams, committees, companies, or other anthropological groups.

Comment: And a minor quibble - the sort of thing we pick up on here - there are seven species of bats that don't hang upside down when sleeping - they make nests. (Yes *nests*, not *a nest*)

Comment: I understand you. However, answer from Edwin says the exact opposite thing and the answer sounds just as reasonable as yours. So I'm now rather confused about which one to accept.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't really one-to-one comparisons, so plurality is not very important. "like a bat" and "as slow as a turtle" are almost set phrases, and you can use them to characterize either an individual or a group. So when you describe a group by comparison with a single item, you're effectively making a statement about each member of the group. E.g.

> They ran as slow as a turtle.

is equivalent to

> Each of them ran as slow as a turtle.

You could say "as slow as turtles", but this isn't as common an idiom. And there's no analogous way to replace "slower than him", since there's no plural form of "him" ("them" makes little sense in this case, since you're comparing with a specific person, unless their gender is unknown and you want to use it as the nonspecific singular pronoun).

Comment: They ran as slowly as a turtle...

Comment: In casual speech it's quite common to use adjectives where adverbs would be more grammatical. For some reason, "as slow as" sounds more natural here. Maybe because even though we say "they ran", we think of it as describing the runners rather than the action. Although when I change it to "They're as slow as" it also feels more natural to use plural "turtles". It's very incongruous.

Comment: They ran as slowly as turtles walk. Yeah, well, I thought we were all being formal here unless stated.

Comment: Nope, this question seems to be about how people actually talk. Even narrators of nature documentaries use informal language like this.

Comment: The posted sentence is standard. But I didn't listen to the video.

Answer (score 1):

- *They're as bright as Einstein* / *the Moon*

shows that there's no grammatical problem in pairing a plural-form subject with a single-form comparator.

- *They hang upside down like a bat*

*is* rather incongruous; 'They hang upside down like bats' is available and is more felicitous on the surface, and would be my choice.

- *They are falling like flies*

is really required; 'like a fly' doesn't work here.

Conversely,

- *They are as straight as an arrow*

would also seem the required form.